# How to uninstall .NET 4.7 on mass across a network/via PDQ

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, .net-framework

I'm looking for a way to remove .Net on multiple machines as I need to install 4.5.2 using either powershell or PDQ Deploy. I can't seem to find a definitive answer. Everything seems to point to a manual uninstall.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ramhound looking to install a sage program that is only supported up to .NET 4.6 ideally 4.5.2 this will be going company wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to remove .Net on multiple machines as I need to
>   install 4.5.2 using either powershell or PDQ Deploy. I can't seem to
>   find a definitive answer. Everything seems to point to a manual
>   uninstall.

What you want is not possible.  It is not possible to remove .NET Framework 4.7.1 from Windows 10 Version 1709.  If you are running Windows 10 Version 1703 then it is possible to uninstall .NET Framework 4.7.1 which would leave you with .NET Framework 4.7.0 which cannot be uninstalled.

> looking to install a sage program that is only supported up to .NET
>   4.6 ideally 4.5.2 this will be going company wide

Any version of Windows 10 can run a program that has been targeted to .NET Framework 4.5.2.  Windows 10 Version 1607 comes with .NET Framework 4.6.2 built-in.  Any version below and including Version 1511 can install .NET Framework 4.6.2

Additionally,

> For example, .NET Framework 4.7 can be used to run applications built
>   for the .NET Framework 4.0 through 4.7. The latest version (the .NET
>   Framework 4.7.1) can be used to run applications built will all
>   versions of the .NET Framework starting with 4.0.

[Install the .NET Framework for developers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers)

Due to the fact 4.x versions of the .NET Framework are in-place upgrades the following statement is true.  So you will be unable to install .NET Framework 4.5.2 on any version of Windows 10 or .NET Framework 4.6.2 on Windows 10 Version 1607+.

> Because the 4.x versions of the .NET Framework are in-place updates,
>   you cannot install an earlier version of the .NET Framework 4.x on a
>   system that already has a later version installed. For example, on a
>   system with Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, you cannot install the
>   .NET Framework 4.6.2, since the .NET Framework 4.7.1 is preinstalled
>   with the operating system.

[Troubleshoot blocked .NET Framework installations and uninstallations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations)

The application you want to run will work on Windows 10 Version 1709 without any configuration change.  **Due to the fact you are using a version of Windows, that has a newer version of .NET Framework built-in, you will be unable to install a older version of .NET Framework**